# TypeError: mat data type = 0 is not supported

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing, imshow

I'd like use `cv2.imshow("Otsu img", binary)` instead of `plt.imshow( binary)`

I got the error

Full code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import io
from skimage.filters.rank import entropy
from skimage.morphology import disk
import numpy as np
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu
import cv2

img = io.imread("scratch.jpg")
entropy_img = entropy(img, disk(10))
thresh = threshold_otsu(entropy_img)

binary = entropy_img <= thresh



cv2.imshow("Otsu img", binary)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

How to fix this error?

```
 cv2.imshow("Otsu img", binary)
TypeError: mat data type = 0 is not supported
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The TypeError can be rectified by converting binary into a `dtype=uint8` using,

```
binary = np.asarray(binary, dtype="uint8")
```

or change the type of binary by using `astype(np.uint8)`

But upon further discussion between Original Poster [@Redhwan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11162983/redhwan), OP identified the problem and following script seemed to solve the issue:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import io
from skimage.filters.rank import entropy
from skimage.morphology import disk
import numpy as np
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("scratch.jpg", 0)
entropy_img = entropy(img, disk(10))
# print type(entropy_img), entropy_img
thresh = threshold_otsu(entropy_img)
# print thresh
# binary = entropy_img <= thresh
ret1, th1 = cv2.threshold(entropy_img, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
# print type(entropy)


cv2.imshow("Otsu img", img)
cv2.imshow("Otsu th2", th1)
# cv2.imshow("OTSU Gaussian cleaned", th3)
# cv2.imshow("OTSU median cleaned", th4)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is not give the error but show me a black window when I converted the variable binary (the output is different from plt.imshow( binary)) . But before calling entropy  is not work with me.

Comment: Try printing out the binary and check whether you have desired values. One nice method would be to print out a (same) subset of the array each step and check whether you are getting results you are expecting). You can edit my answer if you want to.

Comment: type(binary) before and after converting the same <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: Not just binary, print out other variables like entropy and thresh. Once they are calculated, print these variables and explore whether this leads to the all-black window? I assume you have a 0 matrix at one point in your script leading to this. I might be wrong here

Comment: I did it, the same result.

Comment: Did you check whether your steps are indeed giving you what you are expecting? Also, I don't think, you need to convert binary datatype when using cv2.imread(). Also, does your scratch.jpeg looks sensible (I'm sorry, I'm sure you have already done this, just to make sure we have covered all possibilities)

Comment: I think, I get what you are missing! Try this at the very end: cv2.waitKey(). Try something greater than 1, if blank does not work

Comment: I used it like that img = cv2.imread("scratch.jpg", 0), this give me the same result img = io.imread("scratch.jpg")

Comment: Also, are you using an interactive python session ?

Comment: Just curious. Do you get anticipated result when using plt.imshow ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I fixed it by this line after thresh line: ret1, th1 = cv2.threshold(entropy_img, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)